# How to solve differential equation $\left(\frac{dy}{dx}+1\right)\ln \left(\frac{x+y}{x+3}\right)=\frac{x+y}{x+3}$?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

> How to solve differential equation $$\left(\frac{dy}{dx}+1\right)\ln \left(\frac{x+y}{x+3}\right)=\frac{x+y}{x+3}$$

I am not even sure, where to start. Should I begin with using parameters, or does that come later in the solution?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Hint: Define $h(x) = y + x$. Then $\frac{d}{x} h(x) = \frac{dy}{dx} + 1$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\left(\frac{dy}{dx}+1\right)\ln \left(\frac{x+y}{x+3}\right)=\frac{x+y}{x+3}$$
Substitute $u=x+y$ and $w=x+3$:
$$\dfrac {du}{dw}\ln \left(\frac{u}{w}\right)=\frac{u}{w}$$
$$\ln \left(\frac{u}{w}\right)=\frac{u}{w}\dfrac {dw}{du}$$
$$\ln u-\ln{w}=u\frac{w'}{w}$$
$$\ln u-\ln{w}=u(\ln w)'$$
$$uz'+z=\ln u$$
This is a first order linear DE:
$$(uz)'=\ln u$$
$$uz=u \ln u -u+C$$
$$z(u)=\ln u -1+\dfrac Cu$$
Where $z=\ln w=\ln (x+3)$ and $u=x+y $.

Comment: Yes you're right I will use another variable thanks @LutzLehmann

Answer (score 0):

Substitute : \begin{cases} z=x+y \\\\
w=x+3\\\\
\end{cases}

$z'\ln(\frac{z}{w})=\frac{z}{w}$ , Homogenous

Substitute : $$s=\frac{z}{w}$$

$(s'w+s)\ln(s)=s$

$\int\frac{\ln(s)}{s(\ln(s)-1)}ds=\int\frac{-1}{w}dw$

$\ln(s)+\ln(\ln(s)-1)+\ln(w)=\ln(c)$

$\ln(sw(\ln(s)-1))=\ln(c)$

$sw(\ln(s)-1)=c$

$$(x+y)(\ln(\frac{x+y}{x+3})-1)=c$$

Of course, another solution is that the differential equation is exact!